# Splunk extracted field in dashboard

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am sending some data to splunk which looks like:

```
"Start|timestamp:1552607877702|type:counter|metricName:cache|count:34488378|End"
```

And then extracting the fields using a regex:

```
search "attrs.name"="service" | regex (Start)(.*)(End) | extract pairdelim="\"{|}" kvdelim=":"
```

After extraction, I can see the fields (type, metricName, count) under "INTERESTING FIELDS". How do I go about using these fields in a dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`search "attrs.name"="service" | regex (Start)(.*)(End) | extract pairdelim="\"{|}" kvdelim=":" | stats count by metricName`

Or

`search "attrs.name"="service" | regex (Start)(.*)(End) | extract pairdelim="\"{|}" kvdelim=":" | stats count by type`

Or

`search "attrs.name"="service" | regex (Start)(.*)(End) | extract pairdelim="\"{|}" kvdelim=":" | table type, metricName, count`

should all give you a table, which can also be represented as a visualization. You can save any of these, or the original events, as a dashboard panel.

Comment: Worked like a charm from Hermoine! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a field listed in either the "Selected fields" or "Interesting fields" list then that means Splunk has extracted them and made them available for use.  Use them by mentioning them by name in an SPL command such as `table type, metricName, count` or `stats max(count) by metricName`.  Once you have the fields the rest is up to your imagination (and the rules of SPL).